# Plotting/Saving sepcific Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I've been trying to learn python, specifically for data analysis extracting data from a table form (cvs, txt or xlsx). So far, I can read the data correctly, groupby 'Location', and plot specific variables for each groupby 'Location'. But it plots all the Locations one after the other, which is ok, but I can't save individual figures.

Need help with:
1. call to plot specific location, with specific variables. i.e Location A, and variable X Column. 
2. Then display the data used for 1 in a table(figure) form below the plot.
3. Save 1 & 2 to a PDF with Location X as Title.
4. Repeat 1-3 for the next location, or specified location.

The scirpt so far using pandas, numpy and matplotlib:

```
colname = ['Year','Month','Day', 'Date','Location','X', 'Y', 'Z']

df = pd.read_csv('TESTDATA.csv', names = colname, header=0, parse_dates=['Year','Month','Day']) 
df.index = df.Date 
df2 = df.groupby('Location')
df3 = df2 [['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
df4 = df2 [['X']]
df4.plot(kind='bar',subplots=True)
plt.show()

Example of the data set:
Year    Month   Day Date    Location    X   Y   Z
2013    6   12  12-Jun-13   A   1   1   1
2013    6   12  12-Jun-13   B   1   1   1
2013    6   12  12-Jun-13   C   2   1   4
2013    6   12  12-Jun-13   D   4   1   8
2013    6   19  19-Jun-13   E   1   1   1
2013    6   19  19-Jun-13   A   1   1   1
2013    6   19  19-Jun-13   B   2   1   1
2013    6   20  20-Jun-13   C   1   1   4
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   D   12  6   6
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   E   2   2   1
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   A   4   3   6
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   B   30  27  33
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   C   30  21  2
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   D   48  11  11
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   E   60  48  11
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   A   320 34  34
2013    6   25  25-Jun-13   B   19  6   6
2013    6   26  26-Jun-13   C   11  7   1
2013    6   26  26-Jun-13   D   5   4   1
2013    6   26  26-Jun-13   E   210 210 30
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Been scouring other post for help. All do something or other, but not what is needed. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure what the question is here, but the groupby object has two components, the 'group name' and the 'data' associated with the group. If you wish to iterate through the groupby object to do plotting on each group etc. then you iterate as follows: `for group, data in DF.grouby('key'):`. Not sure if this is what you want...?

Comment: Hi Woody, sorry the Q is not clear. I need to sort the data by location (use the groupby method so A's,B's, C's are grouped), then plot for location A, variable X over time, then a seperate plot, Location A, variable Y..below each plot I will add the data later...